# Geojson not displayed on the map

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I would like to create a covid map which uses geojson to download countries from "countries.json" unfortunately the countries do not show on the map

1. Here is the link to my work effects: https://neqts.github.io/map/
2. And here is the link to the source code:https://github.com/neqts/map/tree/master
3. It should looks like this : https://datahub.io/core/geo-countries

Help...

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Map , GeoJSON, MapContainer} from 'react-leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" 

const CovidMap = ({countries}) => {
    console.log(countries);
    return ( <MapContainer style={{height:"90vh"}} zoom={2} center={[20,100]}>
        <GeoJSON data={countries} /> 
    </MapContainer>
    );
}
 
export default CovidMap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just import the countries json, delete local countries variable and pass countries as prop to your `CovidMap` component

```
import countries from "../data/countries.json";

const Covid19 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {countries.length === 0 ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <CovidMap countries={countries} />
          <Legend />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You should see something similar to this:
[image]